# .htaccess - redirect links on page by removing folder from link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, modx-revolution

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.belafontecode.com/how-to-host-multiple-sub-domains-on-modx-revolution/) to manage subdomains for a MODx Revo 2.1.3 installation. The idea is that the htaccess file in the web root folder redirects calls for subdomain.mydomain.com to a folder in the web root directory by the same name as the subdomain, ie /home/mydomain/www/subdomain. Subdomain contains the MODx files to run the page, as well as another htaccess to point all further requests back to the root folder.

The better part of it works; I can view the homepage of the site (which means MODx is doing its part), but none of the links to the css, js, images, etc work, and it seems like the Wayfinder and getResources packages are failing to output. The links that are being used for the images+css+js are /subdomain/assets...etc; I need the links to point directly to the /assets folder. It's like the root .htaccess works to redirect the request to the subdomain folder, but the .htaccess in the folder doesn't point anything back up to the root for the remaining requests.

Here's my root folder htaccess, the 2nd part taken from the tutorial:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The Multiple subdomains part
#REDIRECT SUBDOMAIN TO SUBDIRECTORY OF SAME NAME
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

and the subdomain folder htaccess is simply:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I know the site works; I can access it using a subdomain that hasn't been processed like the tutorial yet. So it's all there, I just need to sort out the link requests. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide an example of 1) a link to js/css/img (e.g. `<img src="URL_HERE">`; 2) The requested URL (e.g. `subdomain.example.com/js/main.js`) 3) how it redirects (check Apache access & error log) and 4) how it SHOULD be redirected.

Comment: As requested:
1.) <img src="assets/images/filename.jpg" />;
2.) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/assets/images/filename.jpg (URL shown in browser)
3.) Output from Apache access log: GET /assets/images/filename.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/
4.) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/assets/images/filename.jpg

All of this is the same for JS and CSS; also a href links are the same.

Comment: How much control do you have over your Apache? If you can edit server config or virtual host -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), restart Apache, try problematic URL and check rewrite log -- you should see exactly what is going on (just try very simple URL and not real page with images etc -- the rewrite log can become HUGE within few seconds if you ave a lot of rewrite rules and many requests -- make experiment as clean as possible). A part of that I may only suggest adding leading slash when referencing resources, e.g. `<img src="/assets/images/filename.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some assistance, I managed to find the solution to this issue.

```
# The Multiple subdomains part
#REDIRECT SUBDOMAIN TO SUBDIRECTORY OF SAME NAME
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.spitfireresources\.com\.?(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/js
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/css
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1,L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%{ENV:REDIRECT_SUBDOMAIN},L]
```

The key line is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/`. Once that was in place everything becomes accessible. Thanks to everyone who commented.